# How to add our external js file in react

Tags: reactjs

Can anybody tell me that how we can external js file into our react component,or in our index.html or in body.

Provide code if possible

Comment: The same way you do it without React: `<script src="path/to/file.js"></script>`. If that doesn't help please provide more information about your problem.

Answer (score 1):

To import an external js file in the React code. You simply need to write a line in **index.html** file.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="name of the file with extension"></script>
```

Or

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="url of the file on server"></script>
```